# M210 DJI Drone expansion port access for payload release

Tags: dji-sdk, payload

I would like to add a payload release system on the Matrice M210 drone.  I have seen the diagram for the expansion port on the rear of the machine.  There is a note in the documentation that says * coming soon.  I am not clear if it referring to this functionality or something else on the page.  Has anyone mapped an external device and been able to access it via Cedence radio?

Any advice or information on how to accomplish this task would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the GPIO pins, the Mobile SDK controls for them are coming soon.

You can achieve this today using the OnboardSDK.